# Can we use that instead of there?

Tags: grammar

> If a man affects anything, it is just **there** that he is deficient.
>
> If a man affects anything, it is just **that** that he is deficient.

I am wondering if we can replace **that** with **there**. There seems to imply a location instead of a thing. However, I think we can actually use it to refer to things, so can we replace that with there, and why not?

Answer (score 0):

No. "There" stands for "in the thing that he is affecting"; "that" would not make sense in that context.

Comment: Isn't "that synonymous to "it"?

Comment: No, because that doesn't contain the sense of "in the thing". But "**in that**" would possibly work.

Comment: so "in that" is synonymous to "there"?